# Print Odd numbers from users input

Tags: java

How can I get all the odds number on the users input. Example: input : "avhguhrgr18543" the output should be "153" but in my code it  gives up to 9... I really need the code that only get the odd number base on the users input.

```
String s;
System.out.println("Input anything you want: ");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
s = scanner.nextLine();

int n = 10;
System.out.println("Odd Numbers are");
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) {
  if(i%2!=0) {
    System.out.print(i + " ");
  }
}
```

Comment: thats because n=10 just take string length as the value of n

Comment: Where in this code are you actually checking to see if an odd number appears in the input? All I see is a 1 -> 10 loop printing each digit.

Comment: You read the user input (`s`), and then completely ignore it when printing the odd numbers. How do you suppose this will ever work?

Comment: Thank you guys, I am new in programming and this really help.

Answer (score 4):

Try,

```
String s = "avhguhrgr18543";
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
  char ch = s.charAt(i);
  if (Character.isDigit(ch) && (ch & 1) == 1) {
                                    // Use bitwise & for performance
       System.out.print(ch);
    }
 }
```

Comment: @kocko, As value save at memory as bit. So, bitwise oprator works much fast than binary operator.

Comment: Of course. I hadn't read the question carefully enough and I didn't know he's interested in odd numbers. :)

Comment: Index of `'0'` in Unicode table is even so for more performance you can remove `-'0'` from your code.

Answer (score 2):

You're not iterating the input characters, you're iterating the numbers between `1` and `10`.

What you have to do is :

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    char next = s.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isDigit(next) && (next - '0') % 2 == 1) {
       System.out.print(next + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot the check if its odd :)

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code,

```
    String s; 
    System.out.println("Input anything you want: "); 
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    s = scanner.nextLine();

    //int n = 10;
    System.out.println("Odd Numbers are"); 

    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++) 
    { 
        char ch = s.charAt(i);
        if(Character.isDigit(ch)  &&  (ch % 2) !=0) 
        { 
            System.out.print(ch + " "); 
        } 
    }
```

**OUTPUT**

> Input anything you want:
>     123456
>     Odd Numbers are 1 3 5

Answer (score 0):

use `isDigit()` function

```
for(i=0;i<s.length();i++)
{
    if(s[i].isDigit())
         //Convert it to int and find if it is odd. Then print it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way will be to reuse Java's regex package with the modulo operator to identify only the odds.